# web-scraping error message: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, fetch

Hello Stack Overflow contributors!

I want to scrape multiple pages of a news website; it shows an error message during this step

```
 response = requests.get(page, headers = user_agent)
```

The error message is

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The lines of code are

```
user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}

#controlling the crawl-rate
start_time = time() 
request = 0

def scrape(url):
    urls = [url + str(x) for x in range(0,10)]
    for page in urls:
        response = requests.get(page, headers = user_agent)   
    print(page)
```

```
print(scrape('https://nypost.com/search/China+COVID-19/page/'))
```

More specifically, this page and pages next to it are what I want to scrape:

https://nypost.com/search/China+COVID-19/page/1/?orderby=relevance

Any helps would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You most probably defined `requests` somewhere else in your code with an integer value.

Comment: adding to @Shreya comment, you must change the variable request to attempts and use f-strings instead format if you're using python3.6+  f'{'Request:{attempts}; Frequency: {request/elapsed_time} request/s'}'

Comment: True! I defined requests somewhere else; after removing, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this code runs okay. I did have to put `request` inside your function. Make sure you do not mix up the module `requests` with your variable `request`.

```py
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}

# controlling the crawl-rate
start_time = time() 

def scrape(url):
    request = 0
    urls = [f"{url}{x}" for x in range(0,10)]
    params = {
       "orderby": "relevance",
    }
    for page in urls:
        response = requests.get(url=page,
                                headers=user_agent,
                                params=params)   

        #pause the loop
        sleep(randint(8,15))

        #monitor the requests
        request += 1
        elapsed_time = time() - start_time
        print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} request/s'.format(request, request/elapsed_time))
#         clear_output(wait = True)

        #throw a warning for non-200 status codes
        if response.status_code != 200:
            warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(request, response.status_code))

        #Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
        if request > 72:
            warn('Number of request was greater than expected.')
            break

        #parse the content
        soup_page = bs(response.text, 'lxml') 
        
print(scrape('https://nypost.com/search/China+COVID-19/page/'))
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I wonder is there a way to add a string for the url? I aim to scrape this page and the following 9 pages https://nypost.com/search/China+COVID-19/page/1/?orderby=relevance

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You could use still `urls = [f"{url}{x}" for x in range(0,10)]` and add `params` to your `requests.get()` as `request.get(url=page, headers=user_agent, params=params` where `params = {"orderby": "relevance"}`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! I meant I want to scrape the pages that are sorted by relevance, the url is in my last comment.
I think you understood me correctly. However, the adjusted code you posted doesn´t work! I printed pages after `for page in urls:
        response = requests.get(url=page,
                                headers=user_agent,
                                params=params)`

Comment: It gives me the pages without params (without "?orderby= relevance"). I would appreciate if you help me fix it.

Comment: This code works for me. If you print `response.url` you see that the params are added.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question, I don't fully get how you make the params and url to iterate pages. I was trying out on a different website: [link] (https://www.startribune.com/search/?page=2&q=China%20COVID-19)  I want to iterate the website to get news from page1,2,3... Could you please let me know what would be the params? Is it `params = {"q": "China%20COVID-19"}`?

Comment: If you would like to respond, I posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938026/how-to-iterate-pages-to-scrape-web-news?noredirect=1#comment109549060_61938026