# How to iterate pages to scrape web news

Tags: python, web-scraping, iterator, web-crawler

I've been trying to figure out how to iterate pages to scrape multiple news articles.

This is the page I want to scrape: (and its following pages)
https://www.startribune.com/search/?page=1&q=China%20COVID-19&refresh=true

I tried out the below code, but it doesn't return a correct result:

```
def scrape(url):
    user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    urls = [f"{url}{x}" for x in range(1,10)]
    params = {
        'q': 'China%20COVID-19'
    }
    for page in urls:
        response = requests.get(url=page,
                                headers=user_agent,
                                params=params) 
    print(page)

print(scrape('https://www.startribune.com/search/'))
```

Please suggest improvements or solutions!

The results I expect are:

```
https://www.startribune.com/search/?page=1&q=China%20COVID-19&refresh=true 
https://www.startribune.com/search/?page=2&q=China%20COVID-19&refresh=true
...
https://www.startribune.com/search/?page=9&q=China%20COVID-19&refresh=true
```

Comment: I added the results I expect in the description.

Comment: Thanks. Right now, your `print(page)` isn't inside the loop, so you'll only see the last value `page` had. If you want to see the full URL, you'll need to concatenate that from the params. Also, your params dict is missing `page` and `refresh`.

Comment: Thanks. Put print(page) inside the loop indeed makes it could print the correct amount of links. The link without refresh also works, so I don't think missing refresh is a problem (but I also tried including that). `urls = [f"{url}{x}" for x in range(1,10)]` and `for page in urls` indicates page. 
The result I got is https://www.startribune.com/search/1
https://www.startribune.com/search/2 ...
And it's still not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, make sure the `params` are complete:

```py
def scrape(url):
    user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
    params = {
        'q': 'China%20COVID-19',
        'refresh': 'true',
    }
    for page_no in range(1, 10):
        params['page'] = page_no
        response = requests.get(url=url,
                                headers=user_agent,
                                params=params) 
        print(response.request.url)
        # https://www.startribune.com/search/?q=China%2520COVID-19&refresh=true&page=1

scrape('https://www.startribune.com/search/')
```

Comment: Thanks! So 'page' is also a parameter? the order of parameters is not important?

Comment: That is correct. Just make sure to update the page parameter since you are iterating through it. Everything that is in the `?...` part is part of the parameters.

Comment: I 'm also wondering how to do deal with iterating pages of new york times. Its website is a bit different. After I click show more, the page parameter does not change. https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=china+COVID-19

Comment: Because the New York Times loads its data dynamically so you need a different way of scraping that data. That is part of a new question, or try to do your homework first and look for "scraping websites with dynamically loaded data".